# Merge of 8-bits data into 16-bits giving wrong result for a specific number all the time

Tags: merge, hex, stm32

I'm getting some 8 bit data from a sensor and trying to merge it into 16 bits. But my code on stm32, doesn't work on 0x63 and 0x91 values. All the other values working except these. Result is 0x6291. What is causing this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9LxM.png)

I tried to merge 0x63 and 0x91 and expected 0x6391 value but I get 0x6291.

Comment: please show your code. Without seeing the code all others can do is make wild guesses.

Comment: AC5 is declared as uint16_t whereas debugger shows it as int16_t. Don't you have AC5 defined multiple times?

Comment: `a=25344 (0x63<<8)     b=-111 (0x91)     result: 0x6291 (25233)` ->  You've successfully added (+) negative number

Answer (score -1, accepted):

before i answer your question i highly recommend you to post a piece of code so we can run it and correct it for you, just to make things easy.
now to answer ur question:

1. it's not happing only in those 2 values, you can check 0x82 0xf5 just the value before 0x63, they changed
2. u are using "+" to merge 2 hex values, u need to use add bitwise "|" and not "+", keep in mind, add is not merge
3. try to use mask after using shift, like: "(HexValue<<8)&0xff00"

Answer (score 1):

AC4 has similarly unexpected value, 0x81f5 assembled from 0x82 and 0xf5. This is due to the fact that you've used int8_t i.e. **signed 8-bit** variable for the single byte. This for bytes which have MSB=1, i.e. negative values, gets expanded during the usual arithmetic conversions, so in this case, the addition is
0xFFFF8200 + 0xFFFFFFF5 = FFFF81F5
which then gets converted to uint16_t as 0x81F5.

In microcontrollers, it's better to try to avoid using signed types and stick to unsigned types, except in well justified cases.

You may have declared the byte array as char; in C, signedness of char is implementation-defined, so unless you use it for characters or text, don't use plain char. Use explicitly unsigned char, or, better, <stdint.h> uint8_t.

JW

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast properly to avoid problems with default integer promotions and signed number shifting.

```
    int8_t v[2] = {0x82,0xf5};

    int16_t val = ((uint16_t)v[0] << 8) | (uint8_t)v[1];
```